# i want to export 2000000 records in csv file but it export only 100000 records in excel sheet while loading data loss occur

Tags: c#

i load data from table.
i want to load 2000000 records should load in few sec in csv file

```
 public static void ExportToCSV(DataTable contentToexport)
        {
            StringBuilder csvData = new StringBuilder();
            csvData.Append("Plant Item,Plant Fullpath");
            csvData.Append(Environment.NewLine);
            int count = 0;
            string contentToExport = "";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();

            HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();

            foreach (DataRow row in contentToexport.Rows)
            {
                csvData.Append(row[0].ToString());
                csvData.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                count++;
                if (count > 200000)
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(csvData.ToString());
                    //contentToExport += csvData.ToString();
                    csvData = new StringBuilder();
                    count = 0;
                }
            }

            if (count < 200000)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(csvData.ToString());
            }

            string attachment = "attachment; filename=export.csv";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/csv";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "public");
            //HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(contentToExport);

            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        }
```

this is shows only few records. otherwise i want to open 2 csv file
 to store this data

Comment: Are you sure your `contentToexport` contains at least 200000 entries?

Comment: What if you try to load export 200 items with the same code? Does it export 100 or 200 (or something different)?

Comment: You can write csv and zip it in server and offer zipped version as attachment.  Try to open the file in notepad++ / visual studio code, you can see all the entries.  Excel will display only first 65k entries approx.